# Necessary and sufficient condition on a set for a continuous function $f$ to be bounded by the subsets

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, upper-lower-bounds

**Question**: Find  a  necessary  and  sufficient  condition  on  the  set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall B \subset A, f(B)$ is bounded, where $f$ is any continuous function $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

**My attempt:** I think the answer should be $A$ must be closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose A is not closed, then we want to show that there exist a function $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and a subset $B$ such that $f(B)$ is unbounded. Since $A$ is not closed, there exist $a_1, a_2, ... , a_n \in A$ such that $a_n \rightarrow a$ and $a \notin A$. Consider the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-a}$ which is continuous on $A$. We can find an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_a(\epsilon) \cap A$ is a subset of $A$. Then $f(B_a(\epsilon) \cap A)$ is clearly unbounded. However, I don't know how to prove the other direction ($A$ is closed $\implies \forall B \subset A, f(B)$ is bounded). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take $A=\Bbb R$ and $f(x)=x$, $A$ is closed in $\Bbb R$ but $f(A)=A=\Bbb R$ isn't bounded.

Comment: @Michelle I think $A$ has to be a proper subset, but what you said still holds for $A=[0,\infty)$ and $B=[1,\infty)$. I think A just has to be compact right?

Comment: On second thought, this might be harder than I thought, especially if $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb R$, such as $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$. It feels like cheating to make the condition that $f(A)$ is bounded, but that's the best I can think of.

Comment: Yes, A compact should do it. It is obviously sufficient condition. To show that it's necessary, if A is not bounded, $f(x)=x$ is not bounded on A. If A is not closed, meaning it has a point $x_0$ on its closure which does not belong to A, $f(x) = 1/ (x-x_0) $ is continuous on A, but not bounded on A. So A must be closed and bounded, i.e. compact.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument that this fails for non closed $A$ is correct, but your conjecture that 'closed' is a sufficient condition is wrong. Take $A= [a, \infty]$ and as $f= id_R$ the identity. Now take $B=A$. I think the correct answer is that the  necessary and sufficient condition you are looking for are **compact sets**. In $\mathbb{R}$ these are exactly the closed & bounded sets and compact sets have nice feature that the images of comact sets by continuous maps are also compact, therefore also closed & bounded. What does it say about images of all $B \subset A$?

Comment: Compactness isn't necessary and sufficient! Take $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ (or any function bounded on the reals) and pick $A=[a,\infty)$. $A$ certainly isn't compact, but $f$ is bounded on all subsets of $A$.

Comment: @doobdoob It appears that the quantifier for $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $\forall$. So, yes, $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ is bounded on all subsets of $A=[a,\infty)$, but $f(x)=x$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

We show that $A$ is closed and bounded (compact) is a NS-condition.

- If $A$ is closed and bounded, $B \subset A$, and $f: A \to \Bbb R$ is continuous, since $f(B) \subset f(A)$ and $f$ is continuous we get the result.
- Suppose $\forall B \subset A, f(B)$ is bounded where $f$ is continous. Take $f=\text{id}$. We see that $A$ is bounded. You already showed that it's closed.